# How can I pass a byte value in c# function

Tags: c#

I have this function in c#:

```
public string CommitDocument(string extension, byte[] fileBytes)
{
   // some code here
}
```

I'm trying to call this function like this:

```
  CommitDocument("document.docx", byte [1493]);
```

I'm getting an error: "Invalid expression term 'byte'". How can I pass a value to the parameter of type byte?

Comment: You have to create, or receive an array of bytes, and then send it to the function.

Answer (score 4):

The byte[] is an array of bytes and you need to allocate the array first with 'new'.

```
byte[] myArray = new byte[1493];
CommitDocument("document.docx", myArray);
```

Answer (score -1):

You defined `CommitDocument` as taking a byte array. A single byte is not convertible into a byte array. Or at least the Compiler is not doing that implicitly. There are a few ways around that limitation:

Provide a overload that takes a byte and makes it into a one element array:

```
public string CommitDocument(string extension, byte fileByte)
{
   //Make a one element arry from the byte
   var temp = new byte[1];
   temp[0] = fileByte;

   //Hand if of to the existing code.
   CommitDocument(extension, temp);
}
```

Otherwise turn `fileBytes` in a `Params` Parameter. You can provide any amount of comma seperated bytes to a `Params`, and the compiler will automagically turn them into an array. See `Params` Documentation for details and limits:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params

Comment: Nevermind this. Andrew B found the real issue.

Comment: @StephenKennedy: I know. I just can not exclude that there is some mistake in the question, wich could make my answer right again :) So I upvoted the one for Andrew and leave it around for some time.

Comment: @StephenKennedy: As this is to make a code example, I opted for the simpler code. Also I prefer to write like this. It gives me better lines at debugging. And the normal and JiT Compiler can still cut it out in release builds.

Comment: Thank you @Christopher! I appreciate your help!